# All id changed to int8

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, npgsql

We updated our Software that we develop from .NetCore2.1 to .NET6.0. We also upgraded all the libraries like EF Core to the newest version.

What we found out now is, that if we migrate now, the migration want to change all the ID of our table to bigint (see example).

```cs
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
    name: "Id",
    table: "Tokens",
    type: "bigint",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(long),
    oldType: "bigint")
    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn)
    .OldAnnotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn)
```

Do you know, why this is happening with the new EFCore6.0?

Comment: Are all of your Id properties of type `long`? If so, that is definitely a `bigint` and should have been that way in the first place.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, because before in EFCore 3.0 the type `long` was somehow migrated into a Postgres type `bigserial` and now they changed it to `bigint`. But I think we have to live with it.

Comment: The mappings and database types are specified by the database provider, not EF Core itself. You're using Npgsql so you you should check for any changes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because there was an intentional major change in version 3.1 of the Npgsql Entity Framework Core provider. You can see the change in the [release notes](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/3.1.html#default-value-generation-strategy-is-now-identity) and instructions on how to opt out of the change:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    => modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right - this is simply a transition from the older "serial" (or "bigserial") column type to the newer "identity" columns. Functionally things should remain the same.

Comment: @Shay I know I'm doing something right when the project maintainer tells me so! Keep up the good work (and I love the ASP.NET standups you do with the other team members too - thanks for that!)